# Weight conversion through function call in c

Tags: function, call

I had a problem statement as following:Define a function that recieves weight of a commodity in kgs and returns the weight in grm,tons,lbs.Call this function from main() and print results in main().
Now my problem is i had understood the theory of pointers but i am not at all able to actually apply that in my program,i just do a guess work if it works ,it works or else i am here.
my code was as follows,which is absolutely wrong:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int weight(float*,float *,float*);
int main()
{
float a,b,c;
weight(&a,&b,&c);
printf("Gram:%f",a);
return 0;
}
int weight(float *grm,float *ton,float *lbs)
{
float kg;
printf("Enter the weight of a commodity in kgs:");
scanf("%f",&kg);
grm=1000*kg;
ton=0.001*kg;
lbs=2.25*kg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is a type mismatch: you're trying to assign a floating value to a pointer (`*grm` is a pointer) in line `grm=1000*kg;` (and similarly for `ton` and `lbs`).

You need to dereference the pointer for `grm` when you assign it.
`*grm = 1000 * kg;`.

Also small nitpick: you don't return anything from your `weight` function, so why not just declare it as `void`?